# Internal and external backlinks

Tags: php, api, web-crawler

I want to find internal and external back-links for each urls of sitemap.xml.

I could get this with the help of seomoz free api. But its taking too much time while extracting data and sometimes hangs in between.

The data extraction process needs to be fast as one sitemap.xml can have thousands of url and i have many such sitemap.xml.

Is there any api or other way (like making a crawler) for finding back-links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this would help you exactly,but there is a tool(plugin) **SEO for Firefox** for firefox browser.
This allows you to export **internal and external links** of a page to a CSV easily.

Comment: Hey , thanx for your reply but data for my urls will get extracted by cron process. So  i think this may not work...still i am trying with this..

Comment: Ok,not familiar with Cron jobs/processes.Hope other forum members will help you. All the best happy coding!